# Perforce sync timestap duration

Tags: logging, synchronization, perforce

I've been tasked with finding out how long a Perforce Depot takes to sync, is it just as simple as looking at the log or is there a command I can search? I'm not really all that familiar with perforce. Thanks.

Comment: This is not on topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

First: to be blunt, this task you have been given is a silly task, for at least two reasons I can think of off the top of my head:

- Syncing a full depot is not at all a typical operation and therefore not a useful operation to benchmark.  Most users will be doing incremental syncs to a workspace that is already mostly in sync, and this will be MUCH faster than syncing a full depot from scratch.  In addition, most users will only ever sync a subset of the depot, rather than the entire thing.
- There are a lot of factors that go into that performance that aren't part of your question.  It'll probably take much longer to sync over VPN than via the local network, and that's mostly a function of bandwidth.  Syncing might also take longer while the server is under heavy load than it does during a period of lighter load.

That said, if you want to find out how long it takes to run a particular `sync` command you can just run:

```
time p4 sync
```

or, if you can't use the `time` command, you can use Perforce's built-in performance tracking:

```
p4 -Ztrack sync
```

which will show you the total time as "lapse".

If you want to get stats on sync commands from normal usage, you can set tracking on all commands and then parse the log, but that goes back to "this is a silly task" because some of those sync commands will be syncing one file and some will be syncing a million.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the is mostly what I am looking for. We are doing some network changes and so I was tasked to sync a subset of the full depot, like a normal end user would (based on their mappings). Kind of to see the overview of the time it takes for a normal user. Does that make sense? Much appreciate that. I knew there was a subset command.

Comment: Okay, that makes a little more sense, but Perforce isn't really the best tool you could use for network benchmarking.  :)  If you did want to try to do a Perforce-based benchmark, though, I'd choose a particular "canonical" set of files (which does not change) and do a series of tests (different times of day, etc) before the change, where in each case you're using an empty client mapped only to that set of files.